# Unable to read values from Nested SortedDictionary in C#

Tags: c#

HI

I am using nested SortedDictionary in my code as **`SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>>`** but not able to use value stored in this object. 
Please find the code which i am using

```
SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>> baseItemCounts = 
     new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>>();
            baseItemCounts.Add("1450", new SortedDictionary<string, int>());
            baseItemCounts["1450"].Add("1450M", 15);
```

I want to print these values on screen. but don't know how to access it.

1450
1450M ==== 15

Please some one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwDevMan81 is correct: baseItemCounts["1450"]["1450M"] will return 15.

If you want to go through the list and return sorted values, try this:

```
        foreach (string key1 in baseItemCounts.Keys)
        {
            foreach (string key2 in baseItemCounts[key1].Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", key1, key2, baseItemCounts[key1][key2]);
            }
        }
```

Remember to iterate by keys so that you get the benefit of the sorting.

Comment: HI All,


Thanks for your support my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

baseItemCounts["1450"]["1450M"] should give you 15 since the first index will give you the Value back (which is the second SortedDictionary), so then you just use the second index to get the Value out of the second SortedDictionary, which is your value.

To print the count values out:

```
     SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>> baseItemCounts = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>>();
     baseItemCounts.Add("1450", new SortedDictionary<string, int>());
     baseItemCounts["1450"].Add("1450M", 10);
     baseItemCounts["1450"].Add("1350M", 20);
     baseItemCounts["1450"].Add("1250M", 30);
     foreach (SortedDictionary<string, int> sd in baseItemCounts.Values)
     {
           foreach (int count in sd.Values)
           {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
           }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

But I want to print it by using foreach. because item may 100+

Answer (score 0):

```
   SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>> baseItemCounts =
  new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>>();
        baseItemCounts.Add("1450", new SortedDictionary<string, int>());
        baseItemCounts["1450"].Add("1450M", 15);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SortedDictionary<string, int>> kv in baseItemCounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(kv.Key);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> x in kv.Value)
                Console.WriteLine(x.Key + "==>" + x.Value);
        }
```

that will do it